# Groovy Schwartzian Transform

Tags: groovy

Can anyone suggest a simpler, more elegant implementation of Perl's [Schwartzian Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) in Groovy?

```
def unsorted = [7, 3, 109, 22, 55]
def sortCriterion = { it + 1 }
def sorted = unsorted.inject([:],{map, v -> map << [(v):sortCriterion(v)]}).sort{it.value}.collect{k,v->k}
assert sorted == [ 3, 7, 22, 55, 109]
```

There must be a better way to get the keys from the sorted map, for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my take on it:

```
def sorted = unsorted.groupBy(sortCriterion).sort().values().flatten()
```

Comment: It's hard to imagine a simpler ST expression than this.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
def sorted = unsorted.collectEntries { v -> [ (v):sortCriterion( v ) ] }.sort { it.value }.keySet() as List
```

Assuming you are using Groovy 1.8 (for the [collectEntries](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#collectEntries%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) method)

Comment: Your submission raises my anticipation for using Groovy 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

in case anyone cares, actual literal translation would be

```
unsorted.collect{[it,sortCriterion(it)]}.sort{it[1]}.collect{it[0]}
```

Comment: Excellent. This topic is incomplete without the faithful analog.